# Xy model without arrows in Metathesis file

Tags: pdftex, xy-pic

First of all, I'm sorry if the question is bad, but I'm desesperate. I'm using the metathesis file that is in this [link](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~donald/metathesis/). The problem is that I entered in the thesis.tex file, and edited it, adding this:

```
\documentclass[dvips,letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
```

After that, I added some text in the chap2.tex file, and added a xy model, that doesn't appear, that is this one:

```
\[
\xymatrix{
& & & & & S\ar[dlll]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\ar[drrr]\\
& & Q1 & & Q2 & & Q3 & & Q4\\
}
\]
```

But It doesn't show me the arrows of the xy model, so I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you are trying to use `tikz-cd` package

Comment: `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` will emulate the standard arrows. But have a look at `tikz-cd`

Comment: I see the arrow tips.

Comment: Note that you have to do `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` in order to get a PDF, with the setup of the template.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are trying to use your template with PDFLaTeX instead of `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` which is totally ok for your very example her. You just have to remove the `dvips` option from your documentclass as I have done below.

I also added an alternative using `tikz-cd` which is much more modern. In order to compile that, you will have to go inside the `thesis.sty` file and remove the `dvips` option from the `graphicx` package. You could also remove that line completely, as you are loading `graphicx` again in your main document.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Figures and Tables}
\label{chap:figtab}
\[
\xymatrix{%
    & & & S\ar[dlll]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\ar[drrr] & & & \\
    Q1 & & Q2 & & Q3 & & Q4
}
\]
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thesistitle
    {Metathesis: \\
     A \LaTeX\ template to Typeset Your Thesis for \\
     Submission to the School of Graduate Studies  \\
     \footnotesize{\sl (Changed the title by modifying the file
      \texttt{thesis.tex})}}
    {\emph{my-name} (change this in \texttt{thesis.tex})}
    {Master of \emph{faculty} \textbf{or} Doctor of Philosophy
     (change this in \texttt{thesis.tex})}
    {Department of \emph{dept-name}
     (change this in \texttt{thesis.tex})}
    {\emph{Month Year} (change this in \texttt{thesis.tex}, too)}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chap2}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
    & &[-1em] S\ar[dll]\ar[dl]\ar[dr]\ar[drr] &[-1em] & \\
    Q1 & Q2 & & Q3 & Q4
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```